# Is BumbleBee installed incorrectly?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, bumblebee, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron N7110 running Ubuntu 12.10. I followed the instructions to install ubuntu & bumblebee on my computer in this thread from the user mikrus: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11647449

Now I have vmware workstation installed and I'd like to enable 3d acceleration on my virtual machines. In order to do so though I have to install primus but I know that I need bumblebee fully working first since primus works with that. Unfortunately though when I run in a terminal:
`optirun glxspheres`

I get:
`[  210.844645] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0.  Please`

[  210.844683] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.

Does this mean bumblebee is installed incorrectly? And if so (or if something else is installed incorrectly), how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!

Originally I had this in my boot parameters which isn't compatible with Bumblebee: `pci=noacpi`

So to fix this I just replaced it with:
`acpi_backlight=vendor`

For those that forgot how to update their grub boot parameters permanently do:
`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Then add the parameter so it's:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Lastly do:
`sudo update-grub
sudo reboot`

Also if you get a different error saying something along the lines of the nvidia module not being installed do:
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`